# How to remove duplicate values in col A from col B in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to remove the values from column B that exist in column A in an Excel spreadsheet. Data > Remove Duplicates doesn't seem to offer this as an option, so how else can I do this? I need to remove the duplicates from column B. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a countif in Column C like `=countif(A:A, B1)`. Then sort columns by C descending and delete out any cells that are greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF( ISERROR( VLOOKUP(B1,$A:$A,1,FALSE) ),B1,"")`

The vlookup checks to see if B is in A, if it isn't then it throws an error.  ISERROR traps the error and the IF lets us do the right thing based on the error.  If B is not in A, then it's value is displayed. Now you can just copy this into col C, and auto-filter the blanks out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [match](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) in column C, dragged down to the end of B, then remove all of the items in B that show `1`

```
 =MATCH(B1,A:A,0)
```